# Ошибка при подтверждении регистрации пользователя в Django

Tags: python, django

После регистрации пользователя появляется ошибка, при которой на почту не приходит письмо подтверждения аккаунта, но при этом пользователь отображается в системе

P.S. Отключил двухэтапную аутентификацию на почтах, с которыми тестировал.

[image: error]

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import RegistrationForm
from .models import Account
from django.contrib import messages, auth
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_encode, urlsafe_base64_decode
from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import default_token_generator
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            phone_number = form.cleaned_data['phone_number']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            username = email.split("@")[0]
            user = Account.objects.create_user(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, email=email, username=username, password=password)
            user.phone_number = phone_number
            user.save()

            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            mail_subject = 'Please activate your account'
            message = render_to_string('accounts/account_verification_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token': default_token_generator.make_token(user),
            })
            to_email = email
            send_email = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message, to=[to_email])
            send_email.send()
            # messages.success(request, 'Thank you for registering with us. We have sent you a verification email to your email adress. Please verify it.')
            return redirect('/accounts/login/?command-verification&email='+email)
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', context)

def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = auth.authenticate(email=email, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, 'You are now logged in.')
            return redirect('dashboard')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid login credentials.')
            return redirect('login')
    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html')

@login_required(login_url = 'login')
def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    messages.success(request, 'You are logged out.')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('login')
 
def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64).decode()
        user = Account._default_manager.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, Account.DoesNotExist):
        user = None

    if user is not None and default_token_generator.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Congratulations! Your account is activated.')
        return redirect('login')
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Invalid activation link')
        return redirect('register')

@login_required(login_url = 'login')
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html')

def forgotPassword(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST['email']
        if Account.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            user = Account.objects.get(email__exact=email)

            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            mail_subject = 'Reset Your Password'
            message = render_to_string('accounts/reset_password_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token': default_token_generator.make_token(user),
            })
            to_email = email
            send_email = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message, to=[to_email])
            send_email.send()

            messages.success(request, 'Password reset email has been sent to your email address.')
            return redirect('login')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Account does not exists!')
            return redirect('forgotPassword')
    return render(request, 'accounts/forgotPassword.html')

def resetpassword_validate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64).decode()
        user = Account._default_manager.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, Account.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    
    if user is not None and default_token_generator.check_token(user, token):
        request.session['uid'] = uid
        messages.success(request, 'Please reset your password')
        return redirect('resetPassword')
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'This link has been expired!')
        return redirect('login')

def resetPassword(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        password = request.POST['password']
        confirm_password = request.POST['confirm_password']

        if password == confirm_password:
            uid = request.session.get('uid')
            user = Account.objects.get(pk=uid)
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Password reset successful!')
            return redirect('login')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Password do not match!')
            return redirect('resetPassword')
    else:
        return render(request, 'accounts/resetPassword.html')
```

Traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/register/

Django Version: 3.1
Python Version: 3.8.8
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'category',
 'accounts',
 'store',
 'carts',
 'orders']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mikezigberman/Desktop/SlWs/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/mikezigberman/Desktop/SlWs/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/mikezigberman/Desktop/SlWs/accounts/views.py", line 44, in register
    send_email.send()
  File "/Users/mikezigberman/Desktop/SlWs/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 284, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/Users/mikezigberman/Desktop/SlWs/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 109, in send_messages
    sent = self._send(message)
  File "/Users/mikezigberman/Desktop/SlWs/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 125, in _send
    self.connection.sendmail(from_email, recipients, message.as_bytes(linesep='\r\n'))
  File "/Users/mikezigberman/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 869, in sendmail
    raise SMTPSenderRefused(code, resp, from_addr)

Exception Type: SMTPSenderRefused at /accounts/register/
Exception Value: (530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError l1sm1235839ejh.57 - gsmtp', 'webmaster@localhost')
```

[image: security]

[image: security1]

Comment: стектрейс в текстовом виде приложите к вопросу, пожалуйста

Comment: добавил к вопросу

Comment: проверьте что права на отправку сообщений есть. у гугла есть такие заморочки. у них нужен пароль приложения

Comment: @ZaArs все права есть, а так же открыт доступ у небезопасным приложениям. В спаме и в удаленных тоже подтверждения регистрации нет.

Comment: попробойте провести процедуру с части Gmail Part https://dev.to/abderrahmanemustapha/how-to-send-email-with-django-and-gmail-in-production-the-right-way-24ab

Comment: @ZaArs посмотрел везде где только можно как добавить пароль к приложению, но у меня в настройках нет этого параметра (фото из гугл аккаунта приложил)

Comment: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?p=WantAuthError&visit_id=637787887203228469-604613680&rd=2#cantsignin&zippy=%2Ci-cant-sign-in-to-my-email-client ссылка из ошибки. там написано что где и куда тыкать. даже ссылки есть чтобы не бродить в  их лабиринтах в поисках нужной страницы